# Cordova on iOS: Camera only works after going back to home screen and then launching app

Tags: ios, cordova

Have been testing a Cordova app on iPhone 4S and iPad Mini  and it has this weird behavior, that when I launch the camera functonality with this code:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.camera', function() {
    if (!navigator.camera) {
        alert("Camera API not supported", "Error");
        return;
    }
    var options = {
        quality: 65,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: 1,
        // 0:Photo Library, 1=Camera, 2=Saved Album
        encodingType: 0,
        // 0=JPG 1=PNG
        correctOrientation: true,
        targetWidth: 700,
        targetHeight: 700
    };

    function addHiddenElement(elementId, imgData) {
        $("<input>", {
            type: "hidden",
            name: "imagedata" + elementId,
            id: "imagedata" + elementId,
            value: "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imgData
        }).insertAfter("#" + elementId);
    }

    function imageData(elementId) {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imgData) {
            addHiddenElement(elementId, imgData);
            //return imgData; 
        }, function() {
            alert('Error, camera functionality not working');
        }, options);
    }
    imageData(this.id);
});
```

Half the time it works fine, but the other half nothing happens. But if I go back to the iOS home screen and then go back the app again (i.e. not restarting the app, just switching back and forth) then the camera works.

I suspect this could be a memory problem but not sure what to do about it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I've the same problem. Did you ever resolve this?